# Add footer divider in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, preferencefragment

A sample preference screen I created:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="GROUP1">
        <Preference
            android:title="ITEM1"
            android:key="ITEM1">
        </Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="GROUP2">
        <Preference
            android:title="ITEM2"
            android:key="ITEM2">
        </Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I want to add a footer divider after each PreferenceCategory.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom layout for your preference category:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#808080" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your preferences XML file, you reference that layout:

```
<PreferenceCategory 
android:title="Preference Title"
android:layout="@layout/<the layout name above>">
```

This is adding a divider above the title, so you would do it for all categories except the first one. You may want to tweak the spacing for the divider.